# interactive 2D animation for the web

Tags: animation, 2d, webgl

Is it possible to make an interactive 2D animation in Blender? For example to let a car drive (over a map) along a path and let it start or stop by clicking?
And if yes, can this be exported for the web?

Even better:  can a 2D picture (a piture of somebody for instance) go through a 3D enviroment along a path by mouseclicking?

Or is this an awkward idea and should I better use other software?

Comment: Blender is better for creating the car and animating it, and finally exporting it.  It isn't designed at the moment for interactivity.  Typically people are working with some other software such as Unreal, Unity, and UPBGE, to create what you are describing.

Comment: Thnx,   I just noticed that UPBGE is the new game engine that works together with Blender. So you mean that when I bring in the 2D animation made in Blender, I can make it interactive in UPBGE. And can't I make an interactive Web aplication from the 2D Blender animation with Verge3D (inspite of the name)?

Comment: The website says it is compatible. I have not worked with Verge 3D so I can't answer questions about it.